# Should I consider byte order when i transfer structure with socket

Tags: c, sockets, byte

```
struct A
{
    int a;
    int b;
};
char data[10];
struct A a;
```

If i use `memcpy()` function to convert `a` into char array `data`,and transfer it with socket.Should i consider byte order now?

Comment: I guess No if you are going to `memcpy()` it back to a same type of structure variable on the other side.

Comment: You most definitely do have to care about byte order. Most machines are little endian, but you can't rely on it.

Comment: Yes, and word size, and compiler alignment rules, and packing, and ... In short you shouldn't send structs over a socket at all. Don't use structs as network protocols. Use network protocols as network protocols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a real project (something that will be deployed in the real world) then yes, you absolutely need to care about byte ordering. You'll also need to care about other serialization issues including data type sizes and structure field alignment.

You can eliminate some headaches by using types explicit sizes, for example use `int32_t` rather than `int`.

The structure field alignment issue is much more involved. The short answer: don't `send()` a raw structure from one machine and `recv()` it on another. Doing so assumes the apps running on both systems lay out their structure fields in precisely the same way (with identical padding).

Answer (score 0):

You probably should, everyone expect network bytes order when receiving data. Another problem that you have is the padding. The compiler is allowed to put empty space between struct members, cause of required alignment. You have to send just one, network-byteordered, struct member at the time to work around this problems. You could look up serialize functions.